# Is Entitlements.plist still necessary for distributions in Xcode 4?

Tags: ios, xcode4, code-signing-entitlements

Is Entitlements.plist still necessary for distributions in Xcode? I've had no problem building ad-hoc distributions without it, but some documentation and many posts still describe it as required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to Ole Begemann](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/06/code-signing-changes-in-xcode-4/) you do not required Entitlements.plist for AdHoc Distribution:

There is a link to [Technical Note TN2250](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TROUBLESHOOTING_GUIDE-CODE_SIGNING_ENTITLEMENTS), which state the details:

> **Code Signing Entitlements**
>
> Previous to Xcode 4.x, it was required
>   that the developer create a Code
>   Signing Entitlements file in the
>   Application Bundle for Ad Hoc testing,
>   that defines the entitlement
>   "get-task-allow" with a value of
>   "false" (un-checked). However with
>   Xcode 4 that is no longer required so
>   long as the application is shared via
>   deferred signing on the Application
>   Archives panel in Organizer. See the
>   section Using the Build And Archive
>   feature of Xcode for Deferred Code
>   Signing for more information.

Comment: so when i get a push notification error that says it has no entitlement, where do I put it?

Comment: @steveCav The entitlements go into the provisioning Profile during the Profile creation. Check the Local and Push Notification Programming Guide http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html